# Searching and recording from a text file in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am looking for some advise on the following search script I have. Any help would be great.

The following line is an example of my input (Query) file ("out.list.txt")

```
IVVTGPHKFNRCPLKKLAQSFTMPTSTFVDI*GLNFDITEQHFVKEKP**SSEEAQFFAK
```

I can find this line and 50,000 others in the alignments file ("out.test.txt") and print the output.
This is an extract from the alignments file.

```
Query_13               388   IVVQADGSQVVEDRKADVMNAAYNALQAGLRTIKVGNTNT*VTEVMNKAIEPFECNMLEG  567
c18644_g2_i1_3         122   LVVGASAETPITGNKADVVLAAYNAIQAALRLIKPGNSNLEVTEVFNKIATDYQCNVLEG  181
c18644_g1_i1_2         121   LVVGATAEAPIAGNKADVTLAAYNAIQAALRLIKPGSTNTEVTQVFNKIAADYHCNVLEG  180
c11476_g1_i1_2         119   VVVQ-DPSAKVTGEKADLLLAALNAMQAALRLVRPGNTNTQVTEAMSKIAEAYGCTMLEG  177
c7710_g1_i1_1          147   IVVSEKADAVVEGRKADVVHAAYNALQVALRLLKPGQKNNDVTEHIAKVVESYKCNPVEG  206
c37_g1_i1_3            145   VVVGKDKSTGAEGRKAEVILAAYNALQASLRHLRPGSKNYDVTETVEKISETFGCNPVEG  204
c2897_g1_i1_3          144   FILGATAENPASGKKADVILAAKQAIDAAVRKIRVGETNLTLTETIARVAAAYGVNSVEG  203
c4999_g1_i1_2          167   VVI---GKEKVDDKRADVVKCAWDAAEAALRLVQVGNTNTQVTEAFTKIADEYGCKPMQG  223
```

If the Query line contains an '*' is it possible to record what is at that position on the other lines of the output? ie. E,E,Q,D,D,T,V

All attempts so far have been unsuccessful and I'm wondering if what I'm attempting is possible.

```
seq_list = open("out.list.txt")

query_sequences = []

for sequence in seq_list:

    query_sequences.append(seq_list.strip())

seq_list.close()

hits = []

alignments = open("out.test.txt")

for line in alignments:

    alignment_hit = line.split()

    for query_sequence in query_sequences:

        if query_sequence in alignment_hit:

            hits.append(line)

            break

alignments.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of desired output based on some input? Specifically, how do you plan on handling the output with multiple *'s? Does the output need to specify which sequence had the * and then the matches? Give us some more details

Comment: I would also like to know how to handle multiple `*` as well as are there multiple "Query" lines in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sequence = open("out.list.txt").read() # reads in the file as a string

alignment_rows = open("out.test.txt").readlines() # reads in the file as a list of lines

# split each row by tab sign "\t" and extract sequences only - third column
# I assume, you're using tab sign as a separator in your alignment
alignment_sequences = [ row.split("\t")[2] for row in alignment_rows ]

output = {} # this is a dict, where keys are indices of positions with * and values are lists e.g. {1: ['A', 'C'], 2: ['D', 'E']}
for index, char in enumerate(sequence):
    if char == "*":
        output[index] = []
        for alignment_sequence in alignment sequences:
            output[index].append(alignment_sequence[index])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the aligning sequence characters, try this (also handles multiple `*` per line)

```
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open('out.test.txt')]
for line in lines:
    data = line.split()
    sequence = data[2]
    if data[0].startswith("Query"):
        star_indicies = [i for i,c in enumerate(sequence) if c == '*']
    else:
        print(list(sequence[star_index] for star_index in star_indicies))
```

Output for your sample input

```
['E']
['E']
['Q']
['D']
['D']
['T']
['Q']
```